# Installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 question

Tags: installation

I want to install Ubuntu. I have Windows 7 already installed. If I install with wubi, will the Windows Boot Manager always show up every time I start up the computer, so that I can choose between Windows 7 and Ubuntu? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes It will show You every time when You running system a selection menu witch system You want to run Windows/Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you go through the WUBI based install , then windows boot loader will have the option for both Ubuntu and Windows .

More information you can find here : [WUBI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi)